# Не выставляется флаг CF при открытии несуществующего файла

Tags: ассемблер, dos, masm32

Есть простой код, написанный под дос, который почему-то работает неправильно.

```
CSEG segment
org 100h

start:
    mov ax, 3D02h
    mov dx, offset just_file
    int 21h
    jc err
ok:
    mov dx, offset msg_ok
    mov ah, 9h
    int 21h
    int 20h
err:
    mov dx, offset msg_err
    mov ah, 9h
    int 21h
    int 20h

file_name db 'command.com', 0
just_file db 'file', 0
msg_ok    db 'file opened$'
msg_err   db 'error$'

CSEG ends
end start
```

Файла с именем file в папке с программой нет, и при запуске скомпилированного com-файла правильно выводится сообщение "error". Но при запуске в отладчике AFD программа выполняется построчно без выполнения необходимых переходов.

В самом начале открывается файл. Т.к. его нет, то флаг CF должен выставляться в единицу. Но этого не происходит, и команда jc err не срабатывает. Что здесь не так?

Comment: Ну, если выполнение отличается под AFD и без него, то это, возможно, проблема самого AFD?

Comment: Наверно, так и есть. Минуту назад запустил программу в CodeView, и и он правильно показал изменение флагов и условные переходы.

Comment: Жалко. Мне всегда нравился AFD, а тут он почему-то слажал.

Comment: А не подскажете еще, что может быть неправильно в этом коде? Выводится сообщение 'cant open the file', хотя файл по этому адресу существует. Может, я не знаю, как надо правильно задавать пути к файлам, которые не лежат в папке с программой? http://pastebin.com/PdETvZUS

Comment: В дампе при этом после строки file_name стоит точка, хотя ее там не должно быть. Все остальные строки идут сплошняком.

Comment: Ну точка в дампе - может двоичный ноль. Вы посмотрите все таки в числовом блоке дампа что там. но вы же данные не меняете по ходу программы, но и в приведенном коде я не вижу пути к файлу, он будет из текущей папки открывать. И вы это под каким-то эмулятором делаете ? Мне просто интересно как AFD умудряется ошибаться, слишком уж грубая ошибка и главное сложно реализуемая отладчиком использующем просто int 3

Comment: Я запускаю все программы под DosBox. Может, он неправильно работает с путями файлов?